# Why pytest-sugar doesn't work in GitLab CI?

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

When tests are launched in GitLab CI, pytest-sugar doesn't show output like in local launching. What the problem can be?

My gitlab config:

```
image: project.com/path/dir

stages:
  - tests

variables:
  TESTS_ENVIRORMENT:
    value: "--stage my_stage"
    description: "Tests launch my_stage as default"

before_script:
  - python3 --version
  - pip3 install --upgrade pip
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt

api:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - pytest $TESTS_ENVIRORMENT Tests/API/ -v
```

**Local:**

[image]

**GitLab:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there's a [problem](https://github.com/Teemu/pytest-sugar/issues/219) with pytest-sugar inside containers. Add `--force-sugar` option to pytest call, it worked for me

Comment: Just adding `--force-sugar` just dumps the final content. This is OK on gitalb but you you are running it on docker you also `-it` e.g `docker run -it  <container> pytest --force-sugar`

Answer (score 0):

By default docker container do not allocate a pseudo-terminal(tty) as a result not stdout, its simple output from console.

There is not clear solution for that case, mostly needs to do workarounds and try special python libraries.